# Constructing explicit coordinates on the Romans space $T^{1,1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, group-theory, kaluza-klein

I am trying to understand coordinates on the space $T^{1,1} = SU(2) \times SU(2) / U(1)$, which shows up in applications of AdS/CFT. It was originally introduced by [Romans](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(85)90479-4) as a compactification of $d=10$ supergravity. My confusion is that there seem to be **two contradictory conventions in the literature for constructing this space**. I suspect this can be resolved simply, but I am struggling to see it.

In Romans' original description, the generators of the left-hand SU(2) factor are $\sigma_i$ and the generators of the right-hand factor are $\tau_I$ (where $i$, $I$ run over the labels 1, 2, 3). Then to define the space $T^{p,q}$ we set $H = p \sigma_3 + q \tau_3$, which makes $H$ the generator of a $U(1)$ symmetry, say $U(1)_H$. Finally $T^{p,q} = SU(2) \times SU(2) / U(1)_H$. The different choices of $p$ and $q$ correspond to different ways of embedding the $U(1)$ divisor in $SU(2) \times SU(2)$, with the choice $p=q=1$ being symmetric.

I would like to set up explicit coordinates on $T^{1,1}$. If $\theta_i$, $\phi_i$, $\psi_i$ are Euler angles on each $SU(2)$ ($i=1$ being the left factor and $i=2$ the right factor), then as far as I can see the action of $H$ moves between different hypersurfaces $\psi_1 + \psi_2 = \text{const}$. Meanwhile, the orthogonal generator $K = \sigma_3 - \tau_3$ generates within such a hypersurface, parametrized by the coordinate $\Psi = \psi_1 - \psi_2$.

This seems to be what is said in [this paper by Gubser](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807164v2); see above Eq. (22):

> The convenience of Euler angles is that we can represent the coset space $T^{pq}$ as the hypersurface $p \gamma_1 + q \gamma_2 = 0$ in the Euler angle coordinatization $(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \gamma_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2, \gamma_2)$ of $SU(2) \times SU(2)$. Writing $\gamma_1 = -q \alpha_3 / \sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$ and $\gamma_2 = p \alpha_3 / \sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$, \ldots

Specifically, my $(\theta_i, \phi_i, \psi_i)$ map to Gubser's $(\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i)$. My generator $K$ will vary the $\alpha_3$ coordinate, and Gubser has chosen the coset representatives in $T^{p,q}$ to lie on $p \gamma_1 + q \gamma_2 = 0$ (although I think any other hypersurface would have done as well).

On the other hand, in [this paper by Candelas & de la Ossa](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(90)90577-z), the space $T^{p,q}$ is defined to be (see second footnote on p.253)

> For general $p$ and $q$ the space $\mathcal{N}_{pq}$ is the set of matrices $(L, R)$ subject to the identification $(L, R) \simeq (L \Theta^q, R \Theta^{p \dagger})$.

Here, $L$ and $R$ are $SU(2)$ matrices,
$$
  L = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & -b^\ast \\ b & a^\ast \end{array} \right)
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  R = \left( \begin{array}{cc} k & -l^\ast \\ l & k^\ast \end{array} \right)
$$
where
$$
  a = \cos \frac{\theta_1}{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\psi_1 + \phi_1)} ,
  \qquad
  b = \sin \frac{\theta_1}{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\psi_1 - \phi_1)}
$$
$$
  k = \cos \frac{\theta_2}{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\psi_2 + \phi_2)} ,
  \qquad
  l = \sin \frac{\theta_2}{2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\psi_2 - \phi_2)}
$$
and $(\theta_i, \phi_i, \psi_i)$ are Euler angles on each $SU(2)$, matching my own notation.

My confusion is that in *this* description it's clear that the identification $(L, R) \simeq (L \Theta, R \Theta^{\dagger})$ shifts
$$
  \psi_1 \rightarrow \psi_1 + \theta
  \qquad
  \psi_2 \rightarrow \psi_2 - \theta .
$$
So the $U(1)$ generated by the matrix $\Theta$ seems to correspond to my generator $K$, not $H$. Specifically $\Theta$ generates changes in $\psi_1 - \psi_2$ and leaves $\psi_1 + \psi_2$ unchanged, which is the opposite of what I think should happen.

Candelas & de la Ossa carefully write $\mathcal{N}_{pq}$ rather than $T^{p,q}$, but as far as I can see the space is *metrically* the same as the one constructed by Romans. He did not give a metric, but Gubser does [his Eq (22)]. This agrees with, eg. [Klebanov & Witten's](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807080v3) Eq. (10) or Candelas & de la Ossa's Eq. (2.11), up to a numerical factor of 2 in some metric components that I think is associated with the "squashing" procedure described by Gubser.

At the same time, I do note that Klebanov & Witten cite Candelas & de la Ossa for their definition of $T^{1,1}$, *not* Romans, even though the Romans paper was five years earlier.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked whether $T^{p,q}=\mathcal N_{p',q'}$ for some $p',q'$, functions of $p,q$?

Comment: @alexarvanitakis: Thanks for the suggestion. As far as I can tell, though, these spaces carry the same metric, which depends on $p$ and $q$. So I think the only possibility is $p' = p$, $q' = q$.

Having said that, the only paper that gives _both_ the generator of the $U(1)$ _and_ the metric is the [Gubser one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9807164v2.pdf). I have checked that metric against, eg. [Klebanov & Witten](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9807080v3.pdf) (their Eq. (10)), and they agree except for numerical factors that I think are associated with the "squashing" mentioned by Gubser.

Comment: "As far as I can tell, though, these spaces carry the same metric" ah yes indeed you write as much in the question (or perhaps that was edited in). Well, that's all you want.
You could try checking whether $H$ is conjugate to $\Theta$ (by a group element  (assuming I understood your notation on a second quick read)) to confirm; this would then construct a diffeomorphism which is also an isometry between the two different presentations of the Romans space.